# Dynamic filter with LINQ (EntityFramework)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

the problem is quite simple. We have some store with many products.
For example each item has fields (and many others):

- Height
- Weight
- Length
- Name
- Color
- Price

We implement some page where we can filter items by range for numbers (like price, length) and string (color).

So, the problem is here:
- we need to allow people to filter items by any of criteria above (color+price, color+length+weight).

The basic approach with predefined SELECT+WHERE is too hard to main.

Is there any other option?

Thank you.

Comment: Plase, post some code...

Answer (score 2):

#### Common Solution

The most common solution is performing a big if` case. It takes some time to support all your fields but will work great at the end.

However, if you want to do it dynamically, 2 third-party libraries can help you with this

---

#### LINQ Dynamic

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/

The syntax required is a little bit different from C# but work great. It's the most popular library to do such a thing.

---

#### C# Eval Expression

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [C# Eval Expression](https://eval-expression.net/linq-dynamic)

The library is not free, but you can do pretty much any dynamic LINQ using the same syntax as C#.

So you will be able to build a string to evaluate and the library will do the rest for you.

Here are some example using EF Classic:

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/Otm0Aa
- https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwTqW7

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan is right. I think using if cases would be easiest and would look something like this.

```cs
var res = _dbContextorSource.table.Where(x => x.ID > 0); //something to get all of them
//or (x => x.ID >= 0 && x.ID <= 50) if you're showing 50 on a page

if(FirstFilterIsUsed){
 res = res.table.Where(x => x.FirstField == FirstFilter);
}

if(SecondFilterIsUsed){
 res = res.table.Where(x => x.SecondField == SecondFilter);
}

//etc
```

I think you could implement a more clean solution that loops through each filter. This is super pseudo but I've used solutions like this.

```cs
var filters = GetUserFilters();
foreach(Filter filter in filters){
 res = res.table.Where(x => x.GetType().
  GetProperty(filter.MatchingName).GetValue(x) == filter.FilterValue);
}
var result = res.ToList();
```